# Stored procedure not updating sql table triggered in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've got site where a table will show a list of assets and their information pulled from a table in sql. I've got a section button where, if necessary, a clerk is able to press and modify existing information by inputting the new within a text or drop down field.  This is done using a stored procedure; everything seems to be running well until you check the work, nothing's been updated!

Here is the code for editing the information;

```
    protected void ADD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DATASYSTEMS"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATING_ASSETS", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ASSET_NUMBER", Txtasset_number.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MACHINE_NAME", Txtmachine_name.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PORT_NUMBER", Txtport_number.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BUILDING_NUMBER", DPBUILDING.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROOM_NUMBER", Txtroom_number.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TELEPHONE_NUMBER", Txttelephone_number.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FLOOR", Txtfloor.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SERIAL", Txtserial.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TYPE", DPTYPE.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BRANCH", DPBRANCH.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SECTION", DPSECTION.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERS", txtuser1.Text);
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "key", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Record has been updated.');window.location='navigation.aspx';</script>");
    }
}
protected void dglocaltables_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

}

and here is the stored procedure that is supposed to update.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[update_TBL_INFO_1] @ASSET_NUMBER as nvarchar(50), @PORT_NUMBER as nvarchar(50), @MACHINE_NAME as nvarchar(50), @TYPE as nvarchar(50) ,  @BRANCH as nvarchar(50), @SECTION as nvarchar(50), @BUILDING_NUMBER as nvarchar(50), @ROOM_NUMBER as nvarchar(50), @TELEPHONE_NUMBER as nvarchar (50), @FLOOR as nvarchar (50), @USERS as nvarchar (50), @ID as float (8), @SERIAL as nvarchar (50) as

If (SELECT ASSET_NUMBER FROM dbo.TBL_INFO WHERE ASSET_NUMBER=@ASSET_NUMBER AND [ID]=@ID)=@ASSET_NUMBER
BEGIN
    If (SELECT MACHINE_NAME FROM dbo.TBL_INFO WHERE MACHINE_NAME=@MACHINE_NAME AND [ID]=@ID)=@MACHINE_NAME
    BEGIN
        If (SELECT PORT_NUMBER FROM dbo.TBL_INFO WHERE PORT_NUMBER=@PORT_NUMBER AND [ID]=@ID)=@PORT_NUMBER
        BEGIN
            If (SELECT [ID] FROM dbo.TBL_INFO WHERE [ID]=@ID)=@ID
            BEGIN

                UPDATE dbo.TBL_INFO
                    SET
                    dbo.TBL_INFO.ASSET_NUMBER = @ASSET_NUMBER,
                        dbo.TBL_INFO.MACHINE_NAME = @MACHINE_NAME,
                        dbo.TBL_INFO.PORT_NUMBER = @PORT_NUMBER,
                        dbo.TBL_INFO.BUILDING_NUMBER = @BUILDING_NUMBER,
                        dbo.TBL_INFO.ROOM_NUMBER = @ROOM_NUMBER,
                        dbo.TBL_INFO.TELEPHONE_NUMBER = @TELEPHONE_NUMBER,
                        dbo.TBL_INFO.[FLOOR]= @FLOOR,
                        dbo.TBL_INFO.TYPE = @TYPE,
                        dbo.TBL_INFO.BRANCH = @BRANCH,
                    dbo.TBL_INFO.[SECTION] = @SECTION,
                        dbo.TBL_INFO.USERS = @USERS,
                    dbo.TBL_INFO.[ID] = @ID,
                    dbo.TBL_INFO.SERIAL = @SERIAL
                                WHERE dbo.TBL_INFO.ASSET_NUMBER=@ASSET_NUMBER
                INSERT INTO dbo.TBL_INFO (ASSET_NUMBER, MACHINE_NAME, PORT_NUMBER, BUILDING_NUMBER, ROOM_NUMBER, TELEPHONE_NUMBER, [FLOOR], TYPE, BRANCH, [SECTION], USERS, SERIAL, [ID]) VALUES (@ASSET_NUMBER, @MACHINE_NAME, @PORT_NUMBER, @BUILDING_NUMBER, @ROOM_NUMBER, @TELEPHONE_NUMBER, @FLOOR, @TYPE, @BRANCH, @SECTION, @USERS, @SERIAL, @ID) 
                SELECT @ID, ACCESS='VALID'

            END

                 ELSE   
                BEGIN
                    SELECT @ID, ACCESS='INVALID'
                END
        END

    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT ACCESS='RESTRICTED'
        END
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT ACCESS='DENIED'      
    END
END
```

GO

where am I going wrong?

Comment: You tagged the question vb.net, but the code is C#?

Answer (score 3):

***You never execute the command!***

You need this at the end of all those .AddWithValue() calls:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```